# Fastest search of a collection of objects by specifying a property of an object in .NET

Tags: .net, search, c#-4.0, collections, binary-search

I'd like to have a Collection that is searchable by the value of a Property in T.  The Property will likely change many times over the life of an instance of T.  The speed of the search is important - linear search is out of the question.

I've successfully used a separate instance of Dictionary, but maintaining another Collection this seems like a kluge.  I hope there is a better way.

One possibility is to use SortedSet class which can keep my Objects sorted ordered by Property.  I can copy the SortSet to an Array and use Array.BinarySearch, but I cannot accept the overhead of creating this array each time I want to search.  Maybe there is some way to use BinarySearch on a SortedSet?

I admit I have seen this question with some answers at least twice, but I could not figure a clear alternative to my Dictionary approach.

I'm using .Net 4.0.

Comment: Is it an equality search? Or a range search? What is the size? (how many records?) are te indexed values unique?

Comment: Equality search, 500-5000 items.  Indexed values are unique.  The property is an auto-generated identifier that is sent to another system as part of a message.  The search occurs when the "other" system replies with a response - then I have to apply the response to my instance of T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you? Of course you can change the underlying set to be something other than a list, and I'm not guaranteeing it works as I wrote it, but the idea is there to keep the list constantly updated.

```
public class Holder
{
    public Action OnPropChange;

    int _prop;
    public int Prop
    {
        get
        {
            return _prop;
        }
        set
        {
            _prop = value;
            OnPropChange();
        }
    }
}

public class SortedListThing : List<Holder>
{
    public void Add(Holder h)
    {
        BinarySortedInsert(h);
        h.OnPropChange = () => { this.Remove(h); base.Add(h); };
    }

    private void BinarySortedInsert(Holder h)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    public void Remove(Holder h)
    {
        h.OnPropChange = null;
        base.Remove(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work and I will implement something like this if I don't hear anything better.